# JAVAFX binding imageview on button(responsive)

Tags: button, javafx, binding, imageview

Here i would like to create a responsive button alongwith imageview,but the problem is imageview not binding properly with button and if i clicked on the button or try to resize the window, automatically the image size increeses and lot of irrelevent scaling problems occuring,eventhough i have'nt set an eventhandler for that button.

This is my sample code

```
public class ImageController extends Application{

private DoubleProperty fontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty(10);

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

FlowPane fp=new FlowPane(); //here i used flowpane to make imagegallery(productview) that will be in responsive in thier position and i tested my problem not with the flowpane

for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
   {

try {
    Button button = new Button();
    button.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", fontSize.asString(), ";")); //button size binded to the scene
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("images/wine.png");
    Image image = new Image(input, 100, 100, true,true);
    ImageView imageView=new ImageView(image);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

    imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(button.widthProperty());  //image size binded to the button
    imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(button.heightProperty());


    button.setGraphic(imageView);

    fp.getChildren().add(button);


} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ImageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

   }
   Scene scene = new Scene(fp, 500, 500);
   fontSize.bind(scene.widthProperty().add(scene.heightProperty()).divide(50));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

you can see my problem dairectly by running my code and resize the window or clicking on button.I need a button alongwith imageview both will resize according to screen resize(responsive)that's all.ThankYou in advance

Comment: did you try "setPreserveRatio (false)" ?

Comment: yes...no change

Comment: If i am not mistaken you can't do that with bindings. You need to call resize() method of your ImageView each time you want to update it's size. Now depending of what you want to do you may need a listener on stage size changes and resize your image

Comment: sorry i have tried,but not working,problem is with imageview when it bind to the button,and button resizes properly

Comment: By doing that and removing the binding you still having the issue? 
button.widthProperty().addListener(e->{ imageView.resize(button.getWidth(), button.getHeight());
});
   
button.heightProperty().addListener(e->{
 imageView.resize(button.getWidth(), button.getHeight());
});

Comment: When i tried the code commented above ,the irrelevent scaling problem of image has stopped,but image is not resizing according to screen size

Comment: Indeed i wasn't on a computer to test it. I had the same issue in the past but i can't remember If i solved it or how. Maybe you could try changing the image dimensions through CSS when the element has reach a specific width or height, i said "Maybe" because i am not sure if that is going to work either.

Comment: FInally i found the solution by binding imageview with scene not with the button,so it worked correctly,thanks for your support.